# Changes to Templates not saved as files

Tags: templates

I have a EE 3.5.6 project. "Save templates as files" is enabled. When a change is made to a template in the Template Manager and saved, I get the notice that the template has been saved, however the change does not appear to be saved to the file (nor on the site). Templates folder permission is set to 777.

I tried dumping the cache, to no avail. The only fix so far is to delete the template and recreate it.

Any ideas why the changes aren't saved to disk?

Comment: Are enclosing directories writable as well?

Comment: is your problem still unsolved?

Comment: It was a permissions issue.